# JDK8 lambda NullPointerException on filter-map

Tags: java, lambda, nullpointerexception, java-8

I have this funny function trying to play with JDK8. It returns from a list of values after a filter procedure of a value against a sibling list the parameter value.

Obviously as collection where I need the value. Since it is a mapping one to one that would be the first element of array.

The result is it breaks with the infamous `NullPointerException`.
While I do know that at least `list1` is not empty. If I put a check on `house.getParkingInfo()` then why not use the old fashion style of simple `if`-clauses to write the same thing?

Is there a style/guide/trick to avoid this `NullPointerException` and be sure it will execute each part of the lambda **if and only if** it has valid data?

```
return listOfPossibleHaircuts.stream().filter(p->p.getParameterDetailId().intValue()==object.getInfo().get("HAIR_STYLE").intValue() ).map(ParameterDetail::getParameterValue).collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your pipeline:

```
return listOfPossibleHaircuts.stream().filter(p->p.getParameterDetailId().intValue()==object.getInfo().get("HAIR_STYLE").intValue() ).map(ParameterDetail::getParameterValue).collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0);
```

To avoid exceptions you must make sure that:

1. `p.getParameterDetailId()` is not null
2. `getParameterValue` doesn't return null
3. the List returned by this pipeline is not empty

I suggest:

```
return listOfPossibleHaircuts.stream()
                             .filter(p->p.getParameterDetailId() != null)
                             .filter(p->p.getParameterDetailId().equals(object.getInfo().get("HAIR_STYLE")))
                             .map(ParameterDetail::getParameterValue)
                             .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                             .findFirst();
```

This will return an `Optional<TheTypeReturnedBygetParameterValue>`.

Feel free to remove any `null` check that is not required (if either `getParameterDetailId` or `getParameterValue` can never return `null`).

You can also chain to `findFirst()` a `.get()` if you are sure the `List` won't be empty.

My solution is assuming that `object.getInfo().get("HAIR_STYLE") != null`. This can be tested before running the `Stream` pipeline, and, as Holger commented, can be used to simplify the filtering:

```
Object result = null;
Object style = object.getInfo().get("HAIR_STYLE");
if (style != null) {
    result = listOfPossibleHaircuts.stream()
                                   .filter(p->style.equals(p.getParameterDetailId()))
                                   .map(ParameterDetail::getParameterValue)
                                   .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                   .findFirst()
                                   .orElse(null);
}
return result;
```

I made another small assumption here - that the `Stream` pipeline should not be executed at all if `object.getInfo().get("HAIR_STYLE") == null`.

Comment: oh ok got it. thanks double or triple filtering and Objects::nonNull is part of the game, which I didn't know. Thank you Eran for the explanation.

Comment: @hephestos note that the first 2 filters can be combined : `filter(p->p.getParameterDetailId() != null && p.getParameterDetailId().equals(object.getInfo().get("HAIR_STYLE")))`

Comment: This only works if `object.getInfo().get("HAIR_STYLE")` is not `null`. But if you assume that, a single `.filter(p -> object.getInfo().get("HAIR_STYLE").equals(p.getParameterDetailId()))` would be enough. Though I would prefer moving that operation out of the stream to avoid evaluating it for every element: `Object val = object.getInfo().get("HAIR_STYLE"); … … .filter(val == null? p -> p.getParameterDetailId() == null: p -> val.equals(p.getParameterDetailId()))`

Comment: @Holger Good point. I assumed that `object.getInfo().get("HAIR_STYLE")` is not null, since that can be checked once before running the `Stream` pipeline. I didn't think about the simplification in the filtering that this assumption allows.